# Need to group every five or so lines of a text file into a single, concatenated line

Tags: python

By way of an example, I have a utf-8 dictionary text file like so:

```
iguanodont
primer
blindfolder
pseudosperm
chanciest
givers
renascent
lecanine
struth
unionizers
autoriser
interpunctuation
monophylies
approximativeness
```

I need to iterate through, group every five lines together (separated by a space), and spit out a new text file, like this:

```
iguanodont primer blindfolder pseudosperm chanciest
givers renascent lecanine struth unionizers
autoriser interpunctuation monophylies approximativeness
```

So far, I've got this. I'm very new, so I apologize this is so banal. Thank-you in advance.

```
import io
dictionary = io.open("shuffled.txt", 'r')
```

Comment: You should probably work through a tutorial or two in Python first, then try to write this.  It should be utterly trivial for you then.  As of now, you really need to make a better attempt than what you've shown here for us to help you.

Comment: I've answered your question, but really this is basic python stuff. That's simple things with a lot ot tutorials about.

Comment: Thanks guys. I do intend to actually learn this—I just needed this ASAP. I do appreciate your help, and I'm sorry for being a nuisance.

Comment: @James: My answer had a little bug. Please look now at my answer I edited it and now all works fine without a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your input file is so huge it won't fit in memory, reading it into a list and **slicing** that list is simplest -- a 3-liner or so:

```
allrows = list(io.open("shuffled.txt", 'r'))
byfive = [allrows[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(allrows), 5)]
io.open('out.txt', 'w').writelines(' '.join(x)+'\n' for x in byfive])
```

Of course you can get much fancier to deal with unbounded files, assured closure in the case of exceptions, and so forth, but it may be best to keep it simple while that's feasible, and add complication only if warranted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
fin = open ('input.txt', 'r')

fout = open ('output.txt', 'w')

lineCount = 0
toAdd = ""
for line in fin:
    if(lineCount == 5):
        fout.write(toAdd + "\n")
        lineCount = 1
        toAdd = ""
        toAdd += line.strip() + " "
    else:
        if(lineCount == 0):
            toAdd += line.strip()
        else:
            toAdd += " " + line.strip()
        lineCount += 1

if(lineCount != 0):
    fout.write(toAdd)

fin.close()
fout.close()
```

with the input.txt as follows:

```
iguanodont
primer
blindfolder
pseudosperm
chanciest
givers
renascent
lecanine
struth
unionizers
autoriser
interpunctuation
monophylies
approximativeness
```

and the output.txt as follows:

```
iguanodont primer blindfolder pseudosperm chanciest
givers  renascent lecanine struth unionizers
autoriser  interpunctuation monophylies approximativeness
```

Comment: @HughBothwell, good point, it's a nasty bug in this too-complicated answer -- `if(lineCount == 5):` it loses the current `line`.  Accepting a buggy answer when many working ones are around -- way to go @James!

Answer (score 0):

```
# assumes Python 3.x
from itertools import zip_longest

INPUT = "shuffled.txt"
OUTPUT = "by_fives.txt"

# from itertools documentation,
# https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def main():
    with open(INPUT) as wordfile, open(OUTPUT, "w") as result:
        wordlist = (line.strip() for line in wordfile)
        for fivewords in grouper(wordlist, 5, ""):
            result.write(" ".join(fivewords) + "\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read_file_name = 'words.txt'
write_file_name = 'words_grouped.txt'

def chunks(l, n):
    """ Yield successive n-sized chunks from l.
        Thanks Ned Batchelder 
    """
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

f = open(read_file_name)
words = f.read()
f.close()

words = words.split("\n")

grouped = list(chunks(words,5))

f2 = open(write_file_name, 'w+')
f2.write(str(grouped))
f2.close()
```

Not exactly what you were asking for but similar. This will generate a list of lists of the grouped data which is then cast to a string and saved to a file.

OUTPUT:

[['iguanodont', 'primer', 'blindfolder', 'pseudosperm', 'chanciest'], ['givers', 'renascent', 'lecanine', 'struth', 'unionizers'], ['autoriser', 'interpunctuation', 'monophylies', 'approximativeness', '']]